# how to find the height of a list python

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

```
p = [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]].
```

I know that len(p) returns the width of a list but how do I get the height of a list which is 3 in this case?

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by width and height.  In your example len(p) is 3.

Comment: One interesting aspect of python is that when you have a list of lists, there's no requirement that every sub-list be the same length. For example, you could have [ [0,0] , [0,0] , [0] ]. In that case you would need to do some extra checking to be sure that you got the length of the correct inner list.

Comment: @user1050548: That last comment sounds more like [LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE) than Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such thing as a "height" of a list. You probably mean "when we choose to represent a matrix as a list-of-lists, what is the height of the matrix"? (sidenote: There are many ways to represent matrices.)

You could take the first row:

```
len(p[0])
```

but you'd run into an error if you had `[]`, so what you want is:

```
len(p[0]) if len(p)!=0 else 0
```

(Other things to keep in mind: if it's acceptable to have an Nx0 matrix represented like `[[],[],[],...]`. I'd say no. Is `[]` how you represent empty matrices? I'd say yes. However some libraries like `numpy` chose differently: `numpy.matrix([]).tolist()`-->`[[]]` and `numpy.matrix([[],[],[]])`-->`matrix([], shape=(3, 0), dtype=float64)`.)

Answer (score 0):

As the other commenters and answers have mentioned, there isn't really a clear definition of what is length and height. It all boils down to measuring dimensions of a multi-dimensional-array.

```
size_of_the_first_dimension = len(p) # length?
size_of_the_second_dimension = max([len(a) for a in p]) # height?
size_of_the_third_dimension = max([len(b) for a in p for b in a]) # depth?
size_of_the_fourth_dimension = max([len(c) for a in p for b in a for c in b]) # colour?
```

... and so on

In general you can measure the nth dimension by a function like the following:

```
def measure(dimension,matrix,aggregator=max):
    if dimension <= 0:
        raise ValueError('dimension must be greater than 0')
    elif dimension == 1:
        return aggregator([len(x) for x in [matrix]])
    else:
        try:
            return aggregator([measure(dimension-1,x) for x in matrix])
        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('matrix is not uniform or does not have %s dimensions' % dimension)

>>> measure(3,[[[1,2],[],[4]],[[3,4,5]],[[3,2],[],[1,2,3,4,5]],[[]]])
5
```

Instead of `max` you could use `min` or something else (passed in as the third argument) if your definition of the size of a dimension is different.